# Parse JSON from website in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, json

Here is the url:
[The Json](https://mangadex.org/api/manga/54666/),
here is the JSON from the website:

```
{"manga":{"cover_url":"\/images\/manga\/54666.jpg?1600241028","description":"&quot;Hi, You.&quot;\r\n\r\nCount Casarius fell victim to a plague and died suddenly, leaving behind a will stating that Rietta, his beautiful young widow of the manor, whom he tried to use as a concubine, be buried alive alongside him. Just before Rietta is buried, Archduke Axias, rumored to be a cruel tyrant, arrives at the funeral to collect the enormous debt Count Casarius still owes him.\r\n\r\n&quot;Everyone here seems to feel sorry for her, and I still have a debt to collect from Casarius&hellip; If I take her instead of debt, I think all of you here should be happy,&quot; he smiled.\r\n\r\n&quot;Hello, Temptress.&quot;","title":"Like the Wind on a Dry Branch","alt_names":["Like a Wind on a Dry Branch","\ub9c8\ub978 \uac00\uc9c0\uc5d0 \ubc14\ub78c\ucc98\ub7fc"],"artist":"Hwa Eum","author":"Moon Seaul, Uret","status":1,"demographic":4,"genres":[8,13,23,36,42,44,45],"last_chapter":"0","last_volume":null,"last_updated":1600241253,"lang_name":"Korean","lang_flag":"kr","hentai":0,"links":{"mu":"172000","raw":"https:\/\/comic.naver.com\/webtoon\/list.nhn?titleId=748535&amp;amp;weekday=wed"},"related":[],"rating":{"bayesian":"8.10","mean":"8.50","users":"28"},"views":5085,"follows":1250,"comments":7,"covers":[]},"chapter":{"1038072":{"volume":"","chapter":"1","title":"","lang_name":"English","lang_code":"gb","group_id":8893,"group_name":"Why Always Scan","group_id_2":0,"group_name_2":null,"group_id_3":0,"group_name_3":null,"timestamp":1600241253,"comments":20}},"group":{"8893":{"group_name":"Why Always Scan"}},"status":"OK"}
```

Here I'm trying to get the text description any idea how to go around it in java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JSON parser that is included in the Android library.

Try the following:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String textDescription = jsonObject.getString("description");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of  JSONObject Class to parse json.[Check this docs for reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject)